# Should this question about "Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean" be closed as a duplicate?

Tags: support, specific-question

I have closed the following question as a duplicate with my hammer.

[Data from 2 tables is not displaying on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67504457/data-from-2-tables-is-not-displaying-on-the-same-page)

Today I visited it again and noticed that the question was reopened. I can't close it again, but I still believe it is a duplicate.

Reasons for believing it's a duplicate:

- "Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean" is an indicator that the error reporting is switched off
- If OP had error reporting enabled they would see the proper error message telling them about ambiguous column name ("Column 'email' in where clause is ambiguous"), which would be trivial to fix given that they already do that in the query, just not consistently.

Should this question remain open or be closed as a duplicate again?

Comment: Because this post lacks disclosure, Dharman (a gold hammer) closed, and another hammer reopened. See [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67504457/timeline). Said reopener also posted an answer (and has been notified of this meta question, because why not?)

Comment: I'm not incline to vote to close, as I don't have the domain expertise and there's a dissenting view in the comments.  Overall, I don't think this warrants a meta post; close as duplicate is not an exact science anyway.

Comment: I disagree. Meta is the only place where such disputes can take place. The person who answered claims that error reporting was not a problem and in their answer they claim that OP should check for errors manually. The error message matches the canonical question.

Comment: Meta isn't for close requests or reopen requests - that's what queues are for. Meta questions that happen to result in closure or reopening tend to have an actual question (for questions that tend to result in reopening, it's typically "how do I improve this question"). You don't.

Comment: @Zoe I can't put the same question into review queue again. I don't even have such capabilities as a gold-badge holder. SOCVR doesn't allow this either. Meta is the only place for such requests if this is the last resort. I have no other options to handle this than here. This is precisely why we have Meta

Comment: No, it isn't. I'm highly aware you can't reclose, but using meta as a means to get people to close on your behalf because you can't is NOT what meta is for. You have no discussion, no question, and no actual point aside "please blindly close this for me". In the context of meta,  that isn't appropriate.

Comment: Odd how when the opposite of this happens it's perfectly fine to post here on meta and results in a hunt... :thinking:

Comment: The [help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) says to do exactly that. I don't see why my question is any different.

Comment: @Zoe Re: Linked post "*We don't need to discuss every single closure on Meta.*" – This isn't "every post", it's an exceptional case (a case where some string of events that's out of the ordinary happened). I agree that more detail maybe should be presented, but this sounds very solidly on-topic for a meta discussion to me.

Comment: Minor point: You've tagged this with [discussion] but it doesn't seem like you're asking for feedback from the community, i.e. you seem sure that the linked post should be closed as a duplicate. If so, I think you should tag this as [support] since you're asking the community to take an action.

Comment: @cigien i mean, voting on the question in question would in fact be feedback, so,

Comment: It was just closed as duplicate again.

Comment: @JeanneDark ... and already has 1 reopen vote.

Comment: Can you ask about closures in the PHP or SQL chatrooms?

Comment: I'm in no way an SME but the fact that there is a dispute over the open/close votes would, in itself, suggest that deletion isn't perhaps the best road to go down.

Comment: @AdrianMole if you wanted a way to freely prevent any closure/deletion, that would be one way of doing so

Comment: ... and it's open again. Closed twice and reopened twice. Call in the arbitration committee!

Comment: @AdrianMole I have no idea why and I lost faith at this point that this can be resolved.

Comment: The reason is simple. Others (at least 4, so far) don't think the question is a duplicate. It's kinda how Stack Overflow works - by *consensus*. Sometimes, other people will have opinions that differ from yours; deal with it, or set up a new website where your opinion acts as a monolith, dictating the rules that others must follow.

Comment: Just because your opinion is 2 doesn't equal 2, does not mean 2 doesn't equal 2.

Comment: This seems like a good reason for gold badgers to be able to close questions with any reason.

Comment: IMO: Let it remain open because the answer accepted by OP doesn't talk anything about "enabling error reporting". This also means OP was asking " How to fetch data from 2 tables?". The current accepted answer shows the way to do it. One can surely tell OP about "enabling error reporting" (from the other/duplicate answer) as a side note or as a recommendation. We can mark it as duplicate but cannot delete the question itself. I see no good reason to delete it.

Comment: "Enabling the error reporting" is not the answer unless that is specifically being asked. The answer was "using table aliases". "Enabling error reporting" is good to have (will help you / will tell you more about the error) but that is not the answer. So, it should not be marked as duplicate as well. You have already written a comment under the Original Question about "reporting" and I think that is enough. (Maybe, you can edit existing answer to add a note on "reporting" for future readers).

Comment: That question seems more like a duplicate of "How to WHERE on column that exists in both table being joined in MySQL?" (I am sure there would already be questions like this on SO)

Comment: The OP to the question at hand has received an answer with three upvotes and has accepted that answer.  There's no more to see here.

Answer (score 7):

### You don't dupe hammer questions so they can be deleted.

Once more, with feeling...

### You don't dupe hammer questions so they can be deleted.

If the question *is* a dupe, then that's fine.  It can be closed as such and allow the OP a chance to read the linked or associated question, or contest it by editing it.

If the question needs to be deleted, that means it's radioactive and the *rest* of us need to be spared.  (To be fair I am getting some readings on my radiometer just *because* it's PHP, but that's not good enough to delete it.)

But once again,

### You don't dupe hammer questions so they can be deleted.

Give the OP a chance to either read the duplicate or edit their question to differentiate it from the duplicate.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232487/discussion-on-answer-by-makoto-should-this-question-about-call-to-a-member-func).